# Need help improving loop performance

Tags: c#

I'm looking for ways to cut costs in this loop. The bottleneck occurs when adding new items to the array. I'm running approx. ten million iterations, so any increase in performance, no matter how small, will go a long way.

```
int[][] coordinates;

public void RefactorCoordinates()
{
    try
    {
        coordinates = new int[10000000][];
        int nextIndex = 0;
        double width = OffsetWidth;
        double height = OffsetHeight;
        double depth = OffsetDepth;
        for (int z = 0; z < width; ++z)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < depth; ++x)
                {
                    coordinates[nextIndex] = new int[] { z, y, x };
                    nextIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        Array.Resize(ref coordinates, nextIndex);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is costing most of the time, the resize of the array afterwards, or the loop? Wouldn't it be simpler to calculate the total size beforehand (as you anyhow declare the coordinates new?) Also, can you not calculate z, y, x based on the index? Just throwing some ideas, don't really know what the intentions are

Comment: the resize of the array is virtually free of cost. if I comment out the line where new items are added to the array, the execution is instantaneous. i'm receiving 3 integer values and creating a new object to represent each increment of those values. that is the only function of the loop

Comment: how about replace the 2d array to dictionary? but it depends on the rest of your programming logic.

Comment: dictionaries are certainly faster for data retrieval, but I don't think they go very far towards reducing initialization overhead. i'm wondering if there's a faster object to instantiate than an array

Comment: changing to a struct seems to have had a significant impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that much of the performance trouble was alleviated by representing data through a struct rather than an array. I'm not sure why this is faster, but whatever works.

Comment: I was going to suggest using a Multidimensional Array: `int [,] coordiantes = new int[10000,3]; The speed up you see is due to memory allocation. As the struct has a fixed size the initialization of the array can now allocate one block of memory.